# pip install Flask-APScheduler Fails

Tags: python, flask, pip, apscheduler

Why are modules so fragile? This is frustrating.

```
   

pip install Flask-APScheduler==1.13.1
  Collecting Flask-APScheduler==1.13.1
  Using cached Flask-APScheduler-1.13.1.tar.gz (12 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Ã— Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  â”‚ exit code: 1
  â•°â”€> [72 lines of output]
      running dist_info
      creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-po_f_m34/Flask_APScheduler.egg-info
      writing /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-po_f_m34/Flask_APScheduler.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-po_f_m34/Flask_APScheduler.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-po_f_m34/Flask_APScheduler.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-po_f_m34/Flask_APScheduler.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-po_f_m34/Flask_APScheduler.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-po_f_m34/Flask_APScheduler.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-po_f_m34/Flask_APScheduler.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      creating '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-po_f_m34/Flask_APScheduler-1.13.1.dist-info'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 366, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 104, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 967, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 97, in run
          bdist_wheel = self.get_finalized_command('bdist_wheel')
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 304, in get_finalized_command
          cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj(command, create)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 860, in get_command_obj
          klass = self.get_command_class(command)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 714, in get_command_class
          self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 202, in load
          module = import_module(match.group('module'))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/normal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 27, in <module>
          from .macosx_libfile import calculate_macosx_platform_tag
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3bomvyn0/normal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/macosx_libfile.py", line 43, in <module>
          import ctypes
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Ã— Encountered error while generating package metadata.
â•°â”€> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

```
libffi-devel is indeed installed.
Python 3.11.7
pip 24.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64 #1
```

I have also tried specifying particular versions but no luck.

```
pip list
Package            Version
------------------ --------
aiohttp            3.9.3
aiosignal          1.3.1
APScheduler        3.10.4
attrs              23.2.0
blinker            1.7.0
certifi            2024.2.2
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
click              8.1.7
Flask              3.0.2
frozenlist         1.4.1
idna               3.6
iso8601            2.1.0
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.3
MarkupSafe         2.1.5
multidict          6.0.5
pip                24.0
PyQt5              5.15.10
PyQt5-Qt5          5.15.2
PyQt5-sip          12.13.0
pytz               2024.1
requests           2.31.0
setuptools         65.5.0
six                1.16.0
twitchio           2.9.0
typing_extensions  4.10.0
tzlocal            5.2
urllib3            2.2.1
Werkzeug           3.0.1
yarl               1.9.4
```

Comment: If _ctypes is missing, it feels like the issue originates from compilation time of python itself.